# Valor random único

Tags: funções, random, chave-primária

Já vi vários posts acerca do assunto mas não é exactamente o que eu procurava.

Há um tempo atrás quando estive em estágio, disseram me para guardar alguns registos com um id random único em cada um, e disseram-me o nome daquele tipo de funções ou algo do género( infelizmente não me lembro como se chamava, dai estar aqui :d ).

Lembro que retornava um valor com letras e números, vejam o exemplo de como era retornado aquele valor, `Xe123e-DE3raw-23weEa-312dWe` era algo deste género.
Se alguém souber de algo parecido, ou nome deste tipo de funções etc. é de grande ajuda, obrigado

Comment: Será [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)?

Comment: Complementando o comentário do @ramaral https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uuid

Comment: Sim, penso que sim, mesmo que não fosse esse que usei aqui há algum tempo, esta solução resolve o meu problema, muito obrigado por responderem a este post ;) abraço

Comment: Idéia: o melhor era se o @ramaral colocasse em formato de resposta. Pq do jeito que está, esta questão aparece nas não respondidas, além dele não ganhar o crédito devido pela resposta. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julgo que aquilo que procura é um [Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

[UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) é um número de 128 bits que na sua forma canónica é expresso por 32 dígitos hexadecimais, divididos em cinco grupos separados por hífen, com a seguinte distribuição: 8-4-4-4-12.

Ex.: `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000`